# JavaScript Помогите оптимизировать код

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы, объекты

Помогите оптимизировать создание таблицы с результатами, перебирая содержимое объектов...

```js
    //БЛОК 1
    var cardsData = [{
      playerTagName: "Вася",
      playerUrl: "/players/",
      playerFirstName: "playerFirstName",
      playerFirstRank: "10000",
      playerSecondName: "playerSecondName",
      playerSecondRank: "20000",
      playerThirdName: "playerThirdName",
      playerThirdRank: "30000",
    }, {
      playerTagName: "Петя",
      playerUrl: "/players/",
      playerFirstName: "playerFirstName",
      playerFirstRank: "10000",
      playerSecondName: "playerSecondName",
      playerSecondRank: "20000",
      playerThirdName: "playerThirdName",
      playerThirdRank: "30000",

    }, {
      playerTagName: "Коля",
      playerUrl: "/players/",
      playerFirstName: "playerFirstName",
      playerFirstRank: "10000",
      playerSecondName: "playerSecondName",
      playerSecondRank: "20000",
      playerThirdName: "playerThirdName",
      playerThirdRank: "30000",
    }];

    const capitalize = (s) => {
      if (typeof s !== 'string') return ''
      return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
    }

    var tableType = 4;
    var absoluteUrl = 'my-game.com';
    var outerWrapper = document.querySelector('#task.rank_table');
    var cardList = document.querySelector('#task.rank_table .inner-wrapper');

    //БЛОК 2 - создание элементов карточки
    var makeElement = function(tagName, className, text) {
      var element = document.createElement(tagName);
      if (className) {
        element.classList.add(className);
      }
      if (text) {
        element.innerHTML = text;
      }
      return element;
    };

    var tableHeader = '<div class="rank_header_row"><div>Тут заголовок</div></div>';

 //БЛОК 3 - создание самой карточки
    var createTable = function(card) {

      var wrapper = makeElement('div', 'rank_wrapper');
      var mainItem = makeElement('div', 'main_rank');
      var tagName = makeElement('div', 'diseasse__title');

      if (tableType === 4) {
        wrapper.innerHTML = tableHeader;
      }
      if (card.playerUrl) {
        var itemLink = makeElement('a', 'tagLink', card.playerTagName);
        itemLink.href = absoluteUrl + card.playerUrl;
      } else {
        var itemLink = makeElement('span', 'tagLink', card.playerTagName);
      }

      tagName.appendChild(itemLink);
      mainItem.appendChild(tagName);

      if (wrapper && card.playerFirstName) {
        var firstItem = makeElement('div', 'first_Rank');
        var firstName = makeElement('div', 'card__name', card.playerFirstName);
        firstItem.appendChild(firstName);
        var firstRank = makeElement('div', 'card__Rank', card.playerFirstRank);
        wrapper.appendChild(firstItem);
      }

      if (wrapper && card.playerSecondName) {
        var secondItem = makeElement('div', 'second_Rank');
        var secondName = makeElement('div', 'card__name', card.playerSecondName);
        secondItem.appendChild(secondName);
        var secondRank = makeElement('div', 'card__Rank', card.playerSecondRank);
        wrapper.appendChild(secondItem);
      }
      if (wrapper && card.playerThirdName) {
        var thirdItem = makeElement('div', 'third_Rank');
        var thirdName = makeElement('div', 'card__name', card.playerThirdName);
        thirdItem.appendChild(thirdName);
        var thirdRank = makeElement('div', 'card__Rank', card.playerThirdRank);
        wrapper.appendChild(thirdItem);
      }
      if (wrapper && card.playerFourthName) {
        var fourthItem = makeElement('div', 'fourth_Rank');
        var fourthName = makeElement('div', 'card__name', card.playerFourthName);
        fourthItem.appendChild(fourthName);
        var fourthRank = makeElement('div', 'card__Rank', card.playerFourthRank);
        wrapper.appendChild(fourthItem);
      }
      if (wrapper && card.playerFifthName) {
        var fifthItem = makeElement('div', 'fifth_Rank');
        var fifthName = makeElement('div', 'card__name', card.playerFifthName);
        fifthItem.appendChild(fifthName);
        var fifthRank = makeElement('div', 'card__Rank', card.playerFifthRank);
        wrapper.appendChild(fifthItem);
      }
      return wrapper;
    };
    //проверка типа нужной таблицы
    if (tableType !== 4) {
      var z = document.createElement('div');
      z.classList.add('rank_wrapper');
      z.innerHTML = tableHeader;
      outerWrapper.prepend(z);
    };
    //БЛОК 4 - заключительный цикл для создания нужного количества карточек
    for (var i = 0; i < cardsData.length; i++) {
      var cardItem = createTable(cardsData[i]);
      cardList.appendChild(cardItem);
    };
```

```html
    <div id="task" class="rank_table">
      <div class="inner-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
```

- Объекты могут быть разной длины.
- Массив очень большой, в примере только 3 объекта.
- Иногда каждому одинаковому ключу нужно добавлять одинаковый элемент, например

```js
var winnerBadge = makeElement('img','winner-bange')
firstItem.appendChild(winnerBadge);
```

Но добавляется он только последнему

Comment: То что по ссылке ваш код?

Comment: Код взят из одного примера. Он работает, потому я его использую. Но хочу научиться упрощать код, рефакторить. Потому и прошу помощи.

Comment: Опишите плз что дано и что с этим надо сделать.

Comment: В Блоке 3 выполняется создание элементов 5 раз, если они есть у объекта, код одинаковый, но разные используются обращения к свойствам объекта.
Можно ли как то упростить эту часть? 
Проблема возникла тогда, когда я хочу добавить каждому из разных свойств одинаковый элемент, объявленный ранее, он добавляется только к последнему элементу из созданных.